# Convert GraphQL query to string with typename

Tags: graphql, apollo, pact

I'm using [Pact](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js) to mock our server side with graphql(Apollo) client. After trying some examples manually I did notice that majority of our current code performs exports like this:

```
import { gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const GET_USER_DETAILS = gql`
  query GetUserDetails {
    current_user {
      id
      first_name
      last_name
      username
      email
      gender
      birth_date
      home_phone
      mobile_phone
      }
  }
`;
```

My question is how can I convert this back to string representation to give to [`withQuery`](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/blob/master/examples/graphql/src/consumer.spec.ts) method of Pact ?

Extra complexity is that we are using Apollo cache which means that I need to add `__typename` to each document which I did using

```
import { addTypenameToDocument } from '@apollo/client/utilities';
addTypenameToDocument(GET_USER_DETAILS)
```

I tried `addTypenameToDocument(GET_USER_DETAILS).loc.source.body` - no `__typename` present here which is causing Pact to fail mocking due to difference on expectation and actual query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `print` from the `graphql` package (which you should probably already have installed).

```
import { print } from 'graphql';

console.log(print(GET_USER_DETAILS));
```